# Perl (opendir): Receiving "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at line 46."

Tags: perl, opendir

I am trying to use opendir to open a directory. When ever this happens I get the error: "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at line." From searching other questions this usually originates from trying to use a variable that is out of scope. From all that I can tell my variable that I am using for my directory location is in scope and my handler for opendir is defined in the function like all examples. Please help me figure out what is going wrong. Line 46 where it is claiming the error is at is double starred.

```
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;
use File::Path;

my @imagelocations = ('/some/location1','/some/location2');
my $destination = '/some/location';

foreach $a (@imagelocations)
{
    find (\&Move_Images, $a);
}

sub Move_Images
{
     my $file = $_;
     if (-e $file && $File::Find::dir eq $a && $file ne ".")
     {
        if (-M $file < 1)
        {
            my @folder = split(/_/, $file);
            my ($var1,$var2,$var3) = @folder[0,1,4];
            if (lc $var1 ne "manual" && lc $var1 ne "test")
            {
                if (-d ($File::Find::dir.'/'.$file))
                {
                    $var3 = substr ($var3,1,-2);
                    my $open = $File::Find::dir."/$file";
                    **opendir (my $dh, $open) or die "Can't open directory $!";**
                    my @files = readdir($dh);
                    ...
```

Comment: can you print $open before **opendir** ? that will lead you to answer.

Comment: @JayKumarR Yes, I can and do print $open before opendir. I just removed this line to simplify the code.

Comment: @xDassx: Please double-check that the line you have marked is the correct one. This error occurs when you are using an undefined value for a file or directory handle, and can't be generated by `opendir`. If the `opendir` had failed and you had no check on it then the following `readdir` would produce the error, but according to the code you show it would have died before that.

Comment: Having said that, a lot of your tests are a little strange in the context of a `File::Find` `wanted` subroutine. There's no need for a `for` loop as you can call `find(\&Move_Images, @imagelocations)` and `find` will process all of the directories in turn. Furthermore, the module will `chdir` to the directory containing each file before it calls your `wanted` routine, so there is in general no need to full-qualify the file name. If you need it, the fully-qualified name is in `$File::Find::name`. `$_` will never be set to `.`, as the pseudo-directories returned by `readdir` are discarded.

Comment: Is the test `$File::Find::dir eq $a` intended to discard anything from a nested directory? If that's what you want then you should use `glob` instead of `File::Find`, as it's doing a lot of work to deliver those nested names to you, only for you to throw them away.

Comment: You might find it useful to work with `$File::Find::name` because that's the path to it

Comment: @xDassx  If this is still a problem, perhaps show/indicate the rest of the code (in brief!).  Cleaning it up as [Borodin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) told you may well do away with the problem -- or expose it.